# Showing Screen Coordinates ONLY on Mouse Down and Mouse Move Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Objective - Show `screenX` and `screenY` coordinates only when events `mousedown` and `mousemove` are occuring simultaneously. When mouse button is released, the `mousemove` event should stop, leaving the coordinates as they are.

Issue - Even when I release the mouse button, the `mousemove` event is still active and the coordinates are changing as the mouse moves.

```js
let xPosition = document.getElementById("x")
let yPosition = document.getElementById("y")

addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  console.log(e.type)
  moveMouse(e.type)
})

addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  moveMouse(e.type)
})

function moveMouse(e) {
  if (e === 'mousedown') {
    addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
      xPosition.textContent = `X: ${event.screenX}`
      yPosition.textContent = `Y: ${event.screenY}`
    })
  }
  if (e === 'mouseup') {
    removeEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      console.log('move mouse event removed.')
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.coordinate-container {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.coordinate-container #x,
.coordinate-container #y {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="coordinate-container">
    <div id="x"></div>
    <div id="y"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not declare some booleans? `let isMouseDown=false`, and then you set that to true on down, and false on up, and now you just need to check that boolean in your mousemove code. If it's true, cool, the mouse is moving while a button is pressed. Don't run "mouse move" related code in your mousedown/mouseup event handlers. Also, remember to bind those same handlers to touchstart/touchend, because mobile devices have been around for a loooong time now =)

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I over looked that simple Boolean approach.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement "touchmove" events, as on tablets and phones, only with a mouse. I did that on my rubix cube simulation. You can see how it works by viewing page source and following the links to the javascript. But essentially, it is the same technique as described in the answer. Save a boolean and add an event to track the movement once it starts. Shill link to my self-promoted and self-authored cube demo, not affiliated with anything else... http://comptune.com/cube.html

Comment: Usually, when I do something like this "mousemove" as part of a project, I will also implement the equivalent "touchmove" event handlers. That way it works whether visitors are using a mouse or a touchscreen. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to set a Boolean, and only update the coordinates when the mouse has been moved and this Boolean is true:

```js
let xPosition = document.getElementById("x")
let yPosition = document.getElementById("y")

let mouseDown = false;

addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
      xPosition.textContent = `X: ${event.screenX}`
      yPosition.textContent = `Y: ${event.screenY}`
  }
});

addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseDown = true);
addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseDown = false);
```

```css
.coordinate-container { position: absolute; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; top: 0; left: 0; width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: blue; } .coordinate-container #x, .coordinate-container #y { width: 100%; height: 75px; color: white }
```

```html
<body> <div class="coordinate-container"> <div id="x"></div> <div id="y"></div> </div> <script src="script.js"></script> </body>
```